# Caracteres especiales en Angular para PDF

Tags: php, angularjs, phpmyadmin, pdf

Hola como estan?? tengo un sistema que hace una cotización en PDF, esta hecha en Angular y trae los datos con PHP a un HTML, el problema que no funcionan los caracteres especiales, el HTML tiene. texto generico con Ñ y funciona por eso debe ser donde trae los otros datos. Saben como puedo solucionar el problema. desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: posiblemente el php, no tenga el formato adecuado o la base de datos o el html o el pdf; generalmente trabajamos con utf-8 o utf-8 sin BOM cuando este disponible.